# Simplifying mathematical expression containing log and product in Maxima

Tags: math, maxima

I wonder how to simplify this expression in Maxima.

```
log(product (exp(-(1/%lambda)*(x[i] -\mu)^a), i, 1, n));
```

### Edit

The following code is not simplifying the expression

```
expand(log(product (exp(-(1/%lambda)*(x[i] -\mu)^a), i, 1, n)));
```

Is there any other possibility?

I know how to solve the expression but I want to do this in Maxima.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ev(foo, logexpand=all)` or `ev(foo, logexpand=super)` where `foo` is the product you stated. Try `? logexpand` to see some documentation (incomplete, however).